# Learning to build real-world .NET apps by example

Tags: c#, .net

I've been doing mainly SQL and front-end HTML/CSS stuff for the past 4 years.  I've done a quite a bit of (procedural) coding in a BASIC-like language, too.  I do not have formal CS training (I have an econ degree).

Now I'm switching gears to OOP in C# .NET full-time.  In order to ramp up, I've been reading about fundamental CS topics (e.g., data structures, algorithms, big-O notation) mainly on StackOverflow and Wikipedia.  I've also read through sections of Code Complete 2, Refactoring, and Head First Design Patterns.

I get the feeling, however, that my approach to becoming a developer is somewhat backwards. I feel like I need to familiarize myself with the available tools in C# and .NET *before* I can truly benefit from learning about how best to apply them.

The part I think I'm missing is sitting down and getting familiar with the .NET framework by actually doing some programming.  I need to get exposure to the day-to-day tasks that go into building a real application.

Since I don't have a mentor, I was wondering if anyone can suggest a book or website that guides beginner programmers through building a (somewhat) real .NET application as a way to teach them the fundamentals.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/

storefront covers everything from design to testing. Should get you started quickly.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/06/24/foundations-of-programming-ebook.aspx

Shows some basic concepts but they are very useful. Includes a sample app to learn from.

Finally,

http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/

ScottGu's blog is full of useful real-world examples and has a ton of links.

And one more note, the book BlueJ offers some great insight into OO if you are new to it.

http://www.bluej.org/

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar position as you and was looking for how a professional would go about designing and implementing a small program from start to finish.  I found these two useful resources:

Rob Conery has a [series of blog posts](http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/mvc-storefront/page/4) where he takes you through how he designed an eCommerce site using ASP.NET MVC.

In a similar fashion, Stephen Walther [builds a forum](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/05/asp-net-mvc-application-building-forums-1-create-the-perfect-application.aspx) using ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to get real world experience through reading as most companies guard their software artifacts (designs, tests, etc.) like gold.  However, sometimes companies will publish their experience with technologies as case studies.  Some of these case studies are no more than marketing crap.  But sometimes, you hit a gold mine of information that gives you insight on a real-world project.  This [Barnes & Nobles case study](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F7%2F7%2F2%2F7721c03b-717e-4f14-a4be-fe6bb40c5a5a%2Fbarnes_noble.pdf&ei=9WT8SbalD9y9twfv5Z3CCg&usg=AFQjCNFJ7dyvZzQqUVCnKj9A7mTclY026Q&sig2=JlAc3JEwXa35A2gRopAAFQ) on the development of a new Data Warehouse does that in part.  Here is a list of some more:
[ASP .Net Case Studies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336563.aspx)
[.Net Case Studies](http://www.microsoft.com/net/CaseStudies.aspx)

Ultimately, software development is driven by business needs and that's where your Econ background could come in handy.  Check out the book [Return on Software: Maximizing the Return on Your Software Investment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321228758) by Steven Tockey when you get the chance.  He goes into things like ROI, IRR, etc.  Things only an Econ major could love :)